# React Native IOS running background tasks

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm just looking for wisdom and a guideline here.

I have a case where I need to run a background task, then send a local notification according to the said task on IOS every morning even if the App is closed.

I searched a lot but can't find a way. I'm just wondering is it really not possible with react-native even at 2022 ?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is not the place to ask that question.